# ¿Por qué razón en España suelen pronunciar los extranjerismos de acuerdo a las reglas del español y no a las reglas del idioma original?

Tags: pronunciación, extranjerismos

En México y América Central los extranjerismos más recientes suelen pronunciarse de acuerdo a las reglas del idioma original, o más comúnmente aproximaciones o deformaciones de estas acercando la pronunciación de los fonemas *extraños*.

Por extranjerismos más recientes me refiero a palabras, usualmente relacionadas con la moda, cine, medicina, computación, etc., que son de uso común pero aún no han sido incorporadas al diccionario.

Ocurre incluso con palabras que han sido ya oficialmente incorporadas al español, por citar un ejemplo, la palabra garaje —de *garage*— en mi país natal suele pronunciarse *garash*, mientras que en España se pronuncia tal como se escribe: garaje.

Ocurre también con siglas, por ejemplo, DVD, mientras en España se pronuncia De-uVe-De, en mi país suele pronunciarse Di-Vi-Di.

Comment: En España, V se dice "uve", por tanto DVD decimos "deuvede".

Comment: En México DVD se dice debede.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración Joul y Alfredo. En cuanto a México, si bien es cierto que DVD se pronuncia "a la española", no estoy seguro de que ocurre con otras, entonces... ¿se usa la pronunciación _cercana a la original_, o se cambia a una pronunciación _a la española_?

Comment: Existen excepciones por ejemplo en España de usa comunmente sandwitch (aceptado por la RAE) y sin embargo existe la expresión emparedado que si se usa en algunos lugares de América Latina.

Comment: @Ernesto Marrero. Para ser exactos, lo que la RAE ha aceptado es "sándwich" y no "sandwitch".

Comment: Este asunto es muy interesante pero complejo. No se puede despachar ni mucho menos con una respuesta a vuelapluma. Para empezar, a veces los extranjerismos “se parecen” a la pronunciación original y otras veces no, pero nunca se conserva la pronunciación original, siempre hay adaptación.

Comment: DVD no es buen ejemplo, el nombre completo tambien se traduce a Disco Versátil Digital.

Comment: ¿Pero solamente en España? También, al contrario, ocurre a otros hablantes nativos cuando tratan de pronunciar palabras castellanas. ¿No conocéis el caso del [nombre del estado de Nevada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevada#Etimolog.C3.ADa_y_pronunciaci.C3.B3n)?

Comment: @Jdamian lo que mencionas es correcto, pero si lees la pregunta va mas en el sentido de que en España se tiende a utilizar las reglas del español, mientras que en América, se tiende a pronunciar la palabra como se hace originalmente en Inglés (u otras lenguas).

Comment: Soy uruguayo y que lástima que los españoles estén dejando de pronunciar las palabras tal como se escriben!!! Por ej toda la vida la ciudad miami fue miami y no maiami, pero nos ganó la alienación del imperio USA. Lástima. Además, como si fuera poco, los indios que encontraron los conquistadores españoles eran los indios miamis, no los indios maiamis. O Florida decir Flórida. Considero que cada persona tiene que hablar en su lengua y no andar pensando como se pronuncia en origen. A veces es lamentable oir palabras alemanas inventando al inglés. Por ej. el barco Spee dicen spi, o se rebanan los

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Por lo que yo tengo entendido, los extranjerismos, específicamente los anglicismos que es de lo que estamos hablando, son palabras de lenguas extranjeras llevadas al ámbito de uso del idioma local, es decir, que el idioma se ha apropiado del término llevándolo a su terreno.

Esto se traduce en, muchas veces, un cambio en la escritura de la palabra, y en la gran mayoría (hablamos de casi el 100%), en un cambio en su pronunciación.

Vemos esto sobre todo en las palabras de nueva aceptación, porque es lo que más cerca nos toca, pero no nos olvidemos que también hay extranjerismos que se adoptaron hace mucho, y que hoy en día usamos día a día, que se pronuncian diferente al original, de los que no nos damos cuenta.

**En la Wikipedia**, la definición de extranjerismo incluye las siguientes líneas:

> ...Puede mantener su grafía y pronunciación original, en cuyo caso se
>   lo llama propiamente barbarismo, o puede adaptarse a la lengua que lo
>   acoge...

Y aquí te dejo la url del original, para que puedas leer el contenido completo:

[Extranjerismo en Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extranjerismo)

Supongo que quizá tu pregunta es más a la par de lo que es un barbarismo que es una forma de extranjerismo que mantiene su grafía y pronunciación original (como dice la wikipedia en las líneas que he puesto encima).

Un saludo

**EDICIÓN:**

Aclaro que para los ejemplos específicos mostrados en la pregunta.

Garaje en España se pronuncia *garaje*, y no *garash*, porque es un extranjerismo adaptado al idioma de destino, tanto en grafía como en pronunciación, probablemente creado en base a la emigración por la época de cosecha de la uva en Francia, mucha gente subía, y bajaba mezclando galicismos con el español, finalmente la RAE incluiría la palabra como la trajeron esas personas, *garaje*, y no *garash*. Además, si nos ceñimos a su origen, deberíamos usar la pronunciación francesa, que creo que tiene una r gutural, que los hablantes de habla hispana (por lo general) son incapaces de pronunciar (sin mucho entrenamiento).

Sobre DVD, al ser siglas, simplemente leemos las letras, que son DVD (*de uve de*). DVD no es una palabra en sí, sino un conjunto de siglas, aunque las palabras que componen DVD sean inglesas, las letras que crean el acrónimo, en principio se pronuncian como en el idioma en el que se hablan.

Supongo que también hace mucho algo comentado en una de las respuestas, que la cultura idiomática de nuestro país es tirando a baja, y por lo tanto, mucha gente habla como lee (vamos, Google no es *guuguel*, es *google*).

De hecho recuerdo una anécdota de un profesor de una universidad de Madrid, que me contó mi padre, nombre del cual no me acuerdo, pero si me viene a la cabeza os informaré, en el que estaba dando una clase sobre literatura inglesa, y pronuncio Shakespeare como *xaquespeare* lo que provoco grandes risas entre los alumnos. 
Alegando que las cosas extranjeras en español se pronuncian como en español, el día siguiente llegó a clase y se dedicó a dar la clase entera en perfecto inglés, para dejar contentos a sus estudiantes.

Como en muchos casos opiniones las hay para todos los gustos: hay quien piensa que deberíamos pronunciar todos los extranjerismos como en español, hay quien piensa que deberíamos poner la pronunciación extranjera, pero al final quien acaba poniendo una pronunciación a una cosa u otra es el pueblo, la mayoría.

Espero que ahora pueda ayudar a despejar las dudas que ha generado mi respuesta inicial, que parecía muy difusa sin las razones de porque los extranjerismos (algunos) han sido adoptados en nuestra pronunciación y no la original.

Comment: Creo que lo esencial de la pregunta no es el tecnicismo entre barbarismo o extranjerismo, sino ¿por qué en España se pronuncian los extranjerismos "mal", como leídos en castellano, mientras que en latinoamérica se han adoptado con la pronunciación original? Es decir, ¿por qué España ha sido menos permeable?

Comment: Hombre, inicialmente, son palabras que se han adoptado al idioma como extranjerismos no barbarismos, obviamente la pregunta no iba por los tecnicismos, pero llegados al punto del DVD o CD-ROM, no podemos evitarlos, ya que si deuvede o cederrón se incluyen en la RAE, es porque formalizando, se han convertido en extranjerismos no barbarismos, como garaje. Apunto que deuvede no aparece en la RAE, aparece DVD. Por otra parte, DVD no dejan de ser siglas, que no están sujetas a ningún idioma, otra cosa sería su significado.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, pero creo que el debate (y la pregunta) no es ése, sino el por qué España ha sido tan poco permeable y se han pronunciado siempre mal (tal y como se leen en español) las palabras adoptadas del inglés, mientras que en otros países no ha sido así. La diferencia técnica entre barbarismo y extranjerismo o lo que ponga o no la RAE no dan una explicación satisfactoria al tema de la mala pronunciación, ¿no? Obedece más bien a razones políticas/sociales/culturales.

Comment: Obviamente los extranjerismos tienen su origen en el pueblo, en como lo pronunciaron ellos, no aparecieron porque sí, está claro. Pero en parte garaje no está mal pronunciado, simplemente es un extranjerismo del francés que se ha adaptado al español, probablemente por la emigración generada por la cosecha de la uva, voy a intentar aclararlo en una edición, pero creo que siguen sin ser malas pronunciaciones, en japón pronuncian muy mal, el inglés, porque su pobre colección de fonemas, nosotros leemos DVD y pronunciamos las letras, ya que DVD no es inglés, aunque las palabras que la compongan sí

Comment: Yo creo que no es nada político, simplemente adaptamos palabras nuevas a nuestro registro lingüistico como siempre se ha hecho en cualquier otro idioma desde la antigüedad. En mi opinión, la pregunta sería por qué en Latinoamérica se conserva la forma original.

Comment: Yo creo que depende de la permeabilidad a lo de fuera. Y al final eso es político, social y cultural. No sólo en Latinoamérica: en muchísimos de países de Europa se conserva la forma (y pronunciación) original de muchas palabras en inglés. El alemán, sin ir más lejos, ha adoptado muchas palabras del inglés y no con pronunciación alemana. España ha sido un país muy poco permeable. Los europeos alucinan de que aquí se doblen absolutamente todas las series, películas, etc... de cine y televisión, por ejemplo. Basta viajar un poco para entender muchas cosas sobre España.

Comment: Está claro yo estuve en Holanda, y todas las series y películas se subtitulan en holandés. Otra razón que se me ocurre es que a los de la RAE hay que conservarlos en formol para sacarlos cada año, sentarlos en sus sillones y que decidan como diremos tal palabra o tal otra, sin ir más lejos que la  "i griega" se diga ahora "yé", demasiada gente mayor dirigiendo el destino de un idioma, lo que costó que entrase cederrón, y mirad como lo hizo, más que razones políticas podemos hablar de lo anticuado de la Academia.

Comment: Vuelvo a comentar para añadir, que en japón pronuncian mal, las palabras extranjeras, por su pobre registro fonético. Y no es nada político, y están muy concienciados con el inglés. En el resto de países de la unión europea se pronuncia como el idioma original, porque el pueblo ha adoptado la palabra de esa manera.

Comment: @JoulSauron En cualquier otro idioma las palabras se incorporan fonéticamente. España debe ser el único país donde "iceberg" se pronuncia "hice ver".

Comment: Pero pasa lo mismo en otros idiomas, en inglés México y Texas se dicen "méksico" y "teksas", no con su pronunciación original náhuatl/española.

Answer (score 11):

Las razones que se me ocurren:

1. España estuvo prácticamente aislada del mundo durante la dictadura, hasta los años 1980.
2. A España Estados Unidos y su poder/influencia le ha quedado muy lejos hasta hace muy poco. En Europa, Francia, Alemania, etcétera han tenido el mismo peso o más que Inglaterra y por proximidad, Francia ha tenido mucha más influencia. De hecho, hasta hace pocas décadas se enseñaba francés como segunda lengua en los colegios, no inglés. Los extranjerismos prestados del francés, por tanto, se han adoptado mucho mejor.
3. Todas las películas, series de televisión, dibujos animados, etcétera... han estado siempre dobladas al castellano, y actualmente a las lenguas autonómicas en muchas regiones (catalán, vasco/euskera, etc). Incluso los títulos de películas, etcétera, se han cambiado a castellano. La gente prácticamente no ha tenido oportunidad de escuchar cómo se pronuncia el inglés hasta hace muy poco.
4. Ha existido siempre, y todavía se conserva, una especie de "patriotismo" igual que ocurre en otras ex-potencias mundiales como Inglaterra o Francia. La antigua dictadura que acabó en 1975 favoreció el "espíritu patriótico español", donde conservar el idioma y no aceptar extranjerismos siempre se ha considerado fundamental. Esto todavía persiste en cierta forma, pero se ha añadido que también con otras lenguas (catalán, euskera, etc) y sus gobiernos nacionalistas se ha comenzado a hacer lo mismo. En Euskadi, toner (de impresora) se ha convertido por ejemplo a "tonerra" en euskera, y así con otras muchas palabras, para que os hagáis una idea de hasta qué punto se le da importancia al lenguaje y la no adopción de extranjerismos en España, como sinónimo de "identidad".
5. Inglaterra y USA han sido enemigos históricos de España, y todavía existe cierta reticencia hacia ellos.
6. La casta política en España, la misma que hace los planes educativos y dirige los medios y televisiones, ha sido siempre bastante inculta, gregaria, y cerrada. Ninguno de nuestros últimos presidentes de gobierno sabe inglés y todos utilizan traducción simultánea en Europa. "Defender lo nuestro" y "sospechar del de fuera" siempre ha dado muy buen resultado electoral. Tanto a nivel de España frente a Europa y el mundo, como en sus propias regiones, cada vez triunfa más el nacionalismo/regionalismo, que incluye poner la lengua "propia" como símbolo nacional. En Cataluña y el País Vasco, por ejemplo, en la escuela se estudia en catalán y euskera, respectivamente, y el castellano se estudia como segunda lengua en la mayor parte de los casos. En el senado de España se ha puesto un sistema de traducción simultánea para que los políticos puedan hablar en catalán, euskera, etcétera. Los políticos españoles sencillamente se han vuelto locos y son actualmente el hazmerreir de Europa con el tema de las lenguas.
7. En general, en España se han impulsado muy poco los idiomas que no sean los locales en el sistema educativo (castellano, euskera, catalán...) y la gente no sabe hablarlos. Se ha considerado que somos tan buenos (nostalgia de un imperio que ya no existe, o de uno que se quiere construir en el caso de los nacionalismos regionales) que se cree que son los demás los que van a venir y deberían aprender los nuestros.
8. Para el caso de DVD y otros, las siglas en España siempre se han leído y se siguen leyendo en castellano, vengan del idioma que vengan. Por el tema del patriotismo que digo, y porque no gustan los extranjerismos, actualmente hemos llegado a la curiosa situación de que CD-ROM oficialmente se puede escribir (y la RAE recomienda que así se haga) "[cederrón](http://dle.rae.es/cederr%C3%B3n)".
9. Sea por lo que sea, siempre se ha considerado un "listillo" y se ha machacado (por envidia) a quien habla y pronuncia bien un idioma. La gente no se esfuerza por aprender a pronunciar, porque en España los idiomas no se valoran, y los que saben hasta casi se avergüenzan de hablarlo bien en presentaciones, etcétera.
10. Mucha de la gente abierta, conocedora de idiomas, etcétera... se ha acabado marchando de España a buscarse un futuro en otros países europeos con mejores oportunidades laborales o donde se reconozca su valor o mérito. Porque, insisto, en España saber idiomas (extranjeros) no se valora y hasta se ve con envidia.

Comment: Sin duda alguna en España nunca se ha enseñado mucho en cuanto a idiomas extranjeros. Lo que no estoy de acuerdo es que se envidie al que los conoce, y se le tache de "listillo", normalmente los listillos son los de barrios altos que para hacer ver que están en la última pronuncian siglas en el idioma inglés porque está de moda. A mi me fascina la gente que sabe hablar idiomas. Los jóvenes somos los que tenemos que impulsar el aprendizaje.

Comment: Por cierto, el punto 10, creo que está de más, la gente no se va de España porque sea un "listillo" por saber idiomas se va porque las oportunidades laborales fuera de España, a nivel postuniversitario (sobretodo en carreras tecnicas) está mejor reconocida fuera que aquí, pero eso es política, y esto es un Q&A de español :P

Comment: Del punto 6 al 10 expresas más una opinión personal y política más que un tema lingüístico...

Comment: Por cierto, que este post está abierto a explicaciones mejores, y sería muy positivo y enriquecedor que se dieran. Estoy muy interesado en escucharlas porque yo mismo también me he hecho esa pregunta muchas veces (y muchos amigos extranjeros me la han hecho a mí también).

Comment: -1 Aunque la respuesta apunta algunas buenas razones posibles, @Laura tiene razón: sobran opiniones y falta justificación. Ojo, no quiero decir que yo discrepe con las opiniones de Pablo; quiero decir que en esta web se esperan respuestas claras basadas en hechos, no opiniones sin más. Pablo: sí, tienes que justificar cada cosa que dices; así funciona esta web. Si no, tu respuesta no es buena.

Comment: -1. Por la retahíla de tópicos y por la ausencia de documentación sobre anglicismos.

Comment: Hay bastante rason de esta respuesta. Lo que si, no es solo caso de España. Por ejemplo los Yankies machacan pronunciacion de absolutamente todo que no es ingles (e incluso muchas palabras que si son inglesas, pero no saben pronunciarlas correctamente).

Answer (score 5):

Aunque esta pregunta sea de hace varios años y tenga ya su respuesta aceptada, un factor que no he visto comentado, en lo que se refiere a la pronunciación de las palabras tomadas del francés al menos, es [la persecución de los "afrancesados"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afrancesado) a principios / mediados del s. XIX.

El excesivo servilismo de los reyes y ministros españoles hacia Napoleón, provocó la invasión de España por los franceses y la instauración de José Bonaparte como gobernante.
Esto derivó en la conocida Guerra de Independencia Española. Durante la misma y en los años posteriores, mostrar costumbres francesas o **pronunciar las palabras igual que los franceses podía verse como un signo de apoyo al invasor**, con riesgo de ser [acusado de traidor y apresado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afrancesado#Represi.C3.B3n), o simplemente linchado por los vecinos.

> El 4 de mayo de 1814 Fernando VII (...) ordenó la persecución de todos los afrancesados (incluyendo a los liberales no colaboracionistas con el régimen napoleónico) que vivían en territorio español.

Ante esta situación, las personas cultas que valoraban su pellejo pero decidieron no exiliarse, se aseguraron de pronunciar "garaje" en vez de "*garash*".

<sup>Nota: en realidad *garage* aún no había entrado en el lenguaje por aquel entonces, pero es por usar el ejemplo de OP.</sup>

Un factor más por el cual hoy día casi nadie pronuncia los galicismos como en francés.

Comment: A ver si nos invaden los ingleses, nos rebelamos y dejamos de pronunciar en inglés :)

Comment: Excelente aporte, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Yo no se swahili, chino, ruso o comanche. No sé cómo se pronuncia una palabra en su idioma original y realmente no es un problema salvo si leo en swahili.

El problema radica en que alguien escribe una palabra en swahili en un texto español. Ese sí sabe como se pronuncia esa palabra y en vez de transliterar su pronunciación y escribirlo como corresponde en español, la escribe tal cual. Yo, la leeré tal cual la leería en español, acento incluido.

Answer (score 1):

"Garaje" no es precisamente una palabra incorporada recientemente al español.

Mi sensación es que en esos países cercanos a EEUU están muy influenciados por este país y toman muchos anglicismos. Están tan acostumbrado a ello que no les importa mucho hacerlo tampoco de otros idiomas. Conozco a gente de allí y es común oír cosas como

> Esto es muy cool (pronunciándo cool como "cul")
>
> Eso tiene un gran handicap (pronunciado handicap como en inglés)

En España la gente no usaría "cool" porque ya existen términos existentes como "guay". La segunda frase la he oído a veces en España, aunque el término handicap, aunque está aceptado por la RAE, no es de uso tan común y la gente suele usar más ejemplo desventaja.

Personalmente en España he notado últimamente una tendencia a usar términos extranjeros en su pronunciación original a diferencia del pasado que no se usaban demasiado. Hay gente incluso que piensa que utilizando estos términos la gente creerá que tienes mayores conocimientos y sobre todo por televisión son usados más frecuentemente por personas de clase social alta. Algo así como que estos términos extranjeros dieran caché a las personas.

Por otro lado hay que tener en cuenta que hay una amplia mayoría en España que no habla ningún idioma además del español. Están acostumbrados a la forma de leer las palabras en castellano y al ver las grafías extranjeras las usarán según las leen.

Comment: Javi, la pregunta no es sobre qué tan a menudo se toma un anglicismo u otro extranjerismo. Es cierto que hay muchas personas que usan alguna palabra en otro idioma porque las hace sentir mas cool (sarcasmo), pero no es mi caso. En lo que a mi respecta, "guay" suena tan extranjero como "cool", pues simplemente sería "chilero". El punto de la pregunta es, ¿por qué tendemos a pronunciarlo diferente?. A mi me parece que lo lógico es incorporarlos de manera fonética, cambiando en todo caso la forma de escribirlo, pero parece que la lógica en la península es distinta y es lo que trato de entender.

Comment: En cuanto a garaje, no quise decir que sea de muy reciente incorporación. Más bien voy al hecho que seguramente no lo notamos con extranjerismos muy viejos, porque simplemente los Ibéricos que se establecieron en América en los últimos 500 años ya las traían así, las pronunciamos igual, y por tanto no notamos la diferencia. Creo que no es el caso de Garaje, aunque la verdad no tengo idea de hace cuando se "adoptó" la palabra en el español, independientemente de cuándo la RAE la haya incorporado al diccionario.

Comment: A mi es que lo de garaje me resulta muy sorprendente que en México se pronuncie como en el francés pues esos fonemas que se usan en la terminación "-age" del francés no se usan en el castellano estándar actual, al menos en España. Es más curioso aún cuando hay una gran cantidad de palabras heredadas del francés que simplemente han sufrido un cambio ortográfico en su terminación "aje -> age" (http://www.nonsolum.com/nonsolum/tableaues2.htm) con el correspondiente cambio fonético. Así de esta manera se cumple la regla de la ortografía (regla Nº 6 en http://www.ortografia.es/se-escriben-con-j/).