# Las palabras chofer y chófer: ¿Cuál de las dos es la original? ¿Por qué surgió la otra?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología

Hasta donde he visto ambas palabras son igualmente correctas y significan lo mismo en español. Pero ¿cuál de las dos es la original?, y ¿por qué surgió la otra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fundeu](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/chofer-y-chofer-dos-formas-validas/) aporta:

> Tanto **chofer** como **chófer**, sin tilde o con ella en la o, son grafías válidas para referirse en español a ‘la persona que, por oficio, conduce un automóvil’.
>
> [...]
>
> En América se emplea mayoritariamente la forma aguda chofer, más acorde con el original francés del que procede (*chauffeur* <sup>1</sup>) y su plural es choferes, sin tilde en la o. En cambio, en España es más común emplear la forma llana chófer y el plural chóferes, con tilde en la o.
>
> Se trata de un vocablo común en cuanto al género (el/la chofer y el/la chófer). No obstante, el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas contempla también como admisible, aunque mucho más infrecuente, la variante *choferesa*.

La lectura de [¿Por qué razón en España suelen pronunciar los extranjerismos de acuerdo a las reglas del español y no a las reglas del idioma original?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2982/5481) puede ser interesante para entender por qué a veces las palabras se incorporan con distinta grafía o pronunciación en nuestro idioma.

Es de suponer, como indica [Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/6915/rodrigo) en los comentarios, que si, citado a Fundeu,  "la forma aguda chofer, [es] más acorde con el original francés del que procede" esta forma (chofer, sin tilde) sea la más antigua en nuestro idioma.

---

<sup>1. El termino significa, [segun wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chofer), "el que calienta" ya que en la Francia del siglo XIX (de donde procede la palabra) se aplicaba también a los fogoneros de las locomotoras.  [Etimologias de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?cho.fer) valida esta referencia.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Según el [Diccioniario de la Real Academia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8xKnYMc), viene del francés *chauffeur*. 
La Real Academia parece preferir la forma **chofer**, ya que [***chófer***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8xKsmql) simplemente remite a [***chofer***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8xKnYMc)

> **chófer** 
>   V. **chofer**.

mientras que en esta entrada es donde recoge la etimología y definición:

> **chofer**  
>   Tb. **chófer**.
>  
>   Del fr. *chauffeur*.
>   1. m. y f. Persona que, por oficio, conduce un automóvil.

Comment: Se agradece la edición, quedó mucho más completo y claro.