# ¿Por qué se dice El iPad/un iPad?

Tags: género, artículos, nombres-propios, extranjerismos

Si **un** iPad es **una** tablet, ¿Por qué se usan artículos **masculinos** para referirse a él?

Suena muy raro si digo **una iPad**, **la iPad**, etc.

No sé si es sólo en Colombia donde se dice así y si en otros lugares es diferente, pero me surgió la duda.

Comment: Parecido a lo que pasa cuando decimos "el internet" en lugar de "la internet" si consideramos que internet es la red de redes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El usar un artículo u otro depende de cómo vayas a pronunciar iPad, que es un nombre en inglés (como [extranjerismo o barbarismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2986/5481)).

En [este artículo](https://www.cnet.com/es/noticias/el-ipad-la-xbox-el-app-como-se-dice-en-espanol/) podemos leer sobre la discusión de si es "el" iPad o "la" iPad

> Debe ser masculino, porque la-iPad (si deletreamos el sonido de la "i" como suena en inglés "ay") se convertiría en una "a" tónica, creando una cacofonía o, en otras palabras, una frase que suena mal (como decir "la agua", pues). Optamos, entonces, por decirle "el" iPad.

Por tanto, poco importa que sea una tablet o tableta (femenino) o incluso que iPad fuese un nombre femenino. La pronunciación llevará a evitar la cacofonía con un artículo masculino.

En [Fundeu ¿el ipad o la ipad?](https://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/el-ipad-o-la-ipad/), también explican que a pesar de que el género de una *tableta* es femenino

> [y aunque] gráficamente comienza por i, se lee /aipad/, y esa ai inicial de su pronunciación funciona como una a fuerte, una a tónica, que es la que recibe el acento de la palabra (como la a inicial de agua, y no como la de amigo).
>
> En español, los sustantivos que comienzan por a tónica llevan, para evitar la cacofonía, el artículo en masculino, con independencia de que ellos sean masculinos o femeninos. Así, decimos el agua, el área o el aula, aunque el resto de sus complementos vayan en femenino: *el agua clara, el área designada, el aula establecida*. Por tanto, aunque creamos que ipad es un sustantivo femenino, lo adecuado es decir el ipad.

Eso sí añaden que

> este cambio en el género del artículo tiene una motivación fonética. Por tanto, allí donde la cacofonía no se dé, no es necesario efectuarlo. Si nuestra pronunciación de la palabra ipad no recoge esa ai inicial inglesa, sino simplemente una i, no hay, en principio, ningún motivo para decir el ipad

Añado que, a pesar de la lógica aplastante de estas entradas, no veo a nadie diciendo "el iPad blanca", pero aparentemente es como debería ser de acuerdo a las reglas.

Comment: la aipad blanca .. tiene lógica pero esta dificil de pronunciar ///// 
el paid blanca ... sigue las reglas pero suena horrible /////
el ipad blanco... rompe con todo pero me gusta